# QueryDSL for Morphia doesn't use converters

Tags: mongodb, querydsl, morphia

I've tried to integrate QueryDSL for Morphia into my project, but it looks like QueryDSL ignores converters.

Morphia-only query works:

```
    return createQuery().field("email").equal(email).get();
```

QueryDSL version throws an exception, because it's not using the converter:

```
    return query(user).where(user.email.eq(email)).fetchOne();
```

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.example.Email

The converters are configured via annotation:

```
@Entity
@Converters(EmailConverter.class)
public class User implements Serializable {
```

This is my Maven setup:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
            <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
          <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

...

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
              <processor>com.querydsl.apt.morphia.MorphiaAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Am I missing some configuration? Or can't converters be used with QueryDSL?

Comment: I just noticed that QueryDSL is still using Morphia 0.105 which is 3 years old. That could cause some issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QueryDSL doesn't support Morphia converters yet. I created a [pull request](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/2035) to add that feature.